# How to find a dynamic frame with contains

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

I am trying to switch my iframe to an iframe that's id changes every time. The source code is here:

```
<iframe class="card-fields-iframe ui-droppable" frameborder="0" id="card-fields-verification_value-f9yavo67out00000" name="card-fields-verification_value-f9yavo67out00000" scrolling="no" src="https://checkout.shopifycs.com/verification_value?identifier=b5fa1aecc18e4f685d7408c699c2ac5b&amp;location=https%3A%2F%2Fyeezysupply.com%2F17655971%2Fcheckouts%2Fb5fa1aecc18e4f685d7408c699c2ac5b%3F_ga%3D2.184035750.1808724638.1545611726-2044927600.1545611726&amp;dir=ltr" title="Field container for: CVV" style="height: 42px;" xpath="1"></iframe>
```

This is what I have tried. This has worked on the other iframes but not working on this one.

```
WebElement cVV = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@src,'verification')]"));
        driver.switchTo().frame(cVV);
```

I also tried with starts-with but still no luck. If there is a different approach that I am not aware of please let me know.

Comment: Also wanted to add that I tried it with different src like "https://checkout.shopifycs.com/verification_value", and Id like "card-fields-verification_value".

Comment: What have you tried with `start-with` ? Because `//iframe[starts-with(@id,'card-fields-verification_value')]` should work.

Comment: @NafRahman Please don't edit the HTML based on which you have received well researched answers. Once you receive canonical answers changing the question can make all the answers invalid and may not be useful to future readers. If your requirement have changed feel free to raise a new question. StackOverflow contributors will be happy to help you out. For the time being I have reverted back the question to it's initial state.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by using title="Field container for: CVV"

```
xpath="//iframe[@title='Field container for: CVV']"
```

Comment: provide bit more html code, if this frame contains in another frame? this locator is good. i tested

Answer (score 0):

To switch to a dynamic `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- You can use the following solution:

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("iframe.card-fields-iframe.ui-droppable[name^='card-fields-verification_value-'][src^='https://checkout.shopifycs.com/verification_value?identifier=']")));
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[@class='card-fields-iframe ui-droppable' and starts-with(@name, 'card-fields-verification_value-')][contains(@src, 'https://checkout.shopifycs.com/verification_value?identifier=')]")));
    ```

Here you can find a relevant discussion on [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

If the HTML Source which is provided is as it is, I would suggest few things.

If you are directly switching to this frame from parent page, may try alternate attributes. Otherwise, make sure you are switching to DefaultContent first and then moving to this frame.

1. Choose other attributes. May be Using `Title` for example. Hope this does not changes.
2. I could see `XPATH="1"` as an attribute too. If that does not changes, you can simply 
   say `iframe[XPATH="1"]`

Answer (score 0):

if you are bent on Identifying `Iframe` based on **SRC** value:

you can use following code using `cssSelector` wildcard `*` i.e. contains sub-string:

```
WebElement cVV = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe[src*='verification']"));
driver.switchTo().frame(cVV);
```